# Typescript how to return 2 different types defined by a generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types, intersection-types

I would like to make an abstract method that returns 2 different types.

It seems with my implementation typescript is expecting an intersection type of the 2 types, however I would like to have a union type of the 2 types: either one or the other.

This is my implementation:

```js
export type ResponseByCategory = {
    cat_a: string,
    cat_b: number
}

export enum Category {
    cat_a = 'cat_a',
    cat_b = 'cat_b'
} 

export type Response<C extends Category> = {
    [c in Category]: ResponseByCategory[c]
}[C]

export function method<C extends Category>():Response<C>{
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
    switch(rand){
        case 0:{
            const a:Response<Category.cat_a> = 'A';
            return a;
            // ^
            // | Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
        }    
        default:{
            const b:Response<Category.cat_b> = 1;
            return b;
            // ^
            // | Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
        }    
    }
}

export const a = method<Category.cat_a>(); // Typescript knows a is a string
export const b = method<Category.cat_b>(); // Typescript knows b is a number
```

With this approach I got the errors when trying to return one or the other type. Typescript is expecting a type `never` to be returned, that is the intersection of `string` and `number`.

Is there a way for Typescript to infer the type I want to return, either one or the other according with the generic type defined in the method?

Of course, this is an oversimplified version of my application. I cannot return a simple union type and I must have some sort of abstraction that can handle lots of different categories.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKwDOkB2ngBCiAwgIYzADm0icAvHAN4BQcbcAxuQPqkBccTDCgBLHJQA0rdlxjcARgJwBXALbzgUZgF9mzUJFhxgK1XDIVqUWi3acepenADks3s6l238p657znHTg9A2h4JBR0LFx8AB5iYxAKHAATTHNyKhoAPidbdgBtDjgxDMsaAF0BDGwIPEISTKtEIoqdAuI2-XAwuAAzZRwOGBE6uFVgGAALCBT4xOS0sqzrbIAKAEo+GpjgeOz8tg46oTgoUlSnAFlyKYA6PoAbCGg1m+m789SIVU2AKgATBsANzSNiYADuIhgHCmay+KQ2hzs9nwcAADHxkSiZCd4Pwdic9hYVog7m5SLkGM4AILOUE4nFQSbKKA4OCkBmM7R2MEolLAPqkZSPGBYvmMzh4uCKQn1eJNGjk-xUuAARi5krYzJgrPZ8k1KJ57D5ul03UM8GOeHxTgm01mCvK1mVckpm1BoSM1tOPgY9pmcxJzVdCnWIOYQA)

Comment: your method is expecting `Response<Category>` but result is `Response<C>` whicg is incompatible

Comment: What I don't understand is why you pass in the generic `C` since the *true* return type is decided at runtime. To me the return type should be `ResponseByCategory[keyof typeof Category]` and there should be no type parameter, but I could be missing something

Comment: @geoffrey I need the generic type `C` so that when I use the method I also know what I am getting in return. The generic `C` is actually coming from the method's parent function and the parent is expecting `Response<C>` in return. By doing this I can assure the implementation is correct.

Comment: @47ndr this method returns number|string *randomly*, it does not depend on any input, thus you can't type that

Comment: (generic type does nothing, as it's not in resulting JS )

Comment: I'm pretty sure the algorithm is deterministic but I would have to agree. You are stuck. If the implementation does not use your generic in any way, it makes sense that you have to assert things at some point. And you would have the same problem with overloads.

Comment: Why don't you just declare the method like that: "export function method() : string|number { ... }'

Comment: Could you [edit] the code here so that it's a [mre] that actually demonstrates your issue?  Right now you're asking something like "can the compiler verify that a randomly generated value at runtime will happen to coincide with a type specified in advance by a developer" and the answer is "no".  If there's some dependency on the implementation of your method on `C`, then please show it.